# We were unable to launch your app from the 'My Apps' launcher

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, office365, azure-active-directory, windows-store

After submitting app to windows store, our app is rejected with the following message.

**"We were unable to launch your app from the 'My Apps' launcher. When we launch your app from the My Apps launcher, during an authenticated O365 session, we are prompted to re-authenticate to your app."**

What we did is, once the user logs into our app with o365 credentials, our app gets added to user's O365 my apps dashboard. When the user clicks on, our app in O365 launcher it launches the login page of our app instead of automatic login.

Step-by-step:

1. User visits our web page "http://portal.myedutor.com/users/sign_in"
2. User clicks on "Login with Microsoft credentials"
3. User signs in using O365 account
4. Now user has an active session with our application
5. User visits "http://portal.office.com" and signs in using same credentials
6. Within a couple of minutes user sees the "IGNITOR" app in "O365 My Apps dashboard"
7. Clicking on the app user is taken to the homepage of our application

Now the problem we are facing is, once the user clicks on our app in step-7 he is again asked to login, we are not able to send any session information on app click. We are using open ID protocol for SSO.

Kindly guide us how to maintain session in such scenario. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: Its not working.. can u help me pleasE?

Comment: Once user clicks on our app in O365 dashboard, user is redirecting to our website. This redirection is triggered by Microsoft Server's. Our guess is, along with this redirection step, Microsoft auth server should send some params, or token which are used for auto-sign in. We are not sure this  (redirection + sign in params) is expected or not. But we are not receiving any param, token from Microsoft in redirection, this is leading our server to launch login page again. This makes the auto-login fail. 

Our question is redirection includes any params / token / cookie?

Comment: Could you make sure when you register your app with Active Directory, the SIGN-ON URL is the Office 365 redirect URL, not http://portal.myedutor.com/users/sign_in?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that might be missed here is when you register your app with Active Directory, you used the main login page for SIGN-ON URL, aka, http://portal.myedutor.com/users/sign_in.

However, in order to directly redirect you to the Office 365 login page, you should use Office 365 redirect URL in this case.

For example, when I was testing it locally, I make sure I used localhost:xxxx/account/singin for my SIGN-ON URL, like below,

[image]